# how can I make a browser plugin that open a program? As skype does

Tags: plugins, browser

For example, when you go on Itunes website and you choose an app, immediately the browser starts iTunes on your pc...

How can I do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype defines a `callto` protocol. You can see this by opening command prompt (assuming Windows)

```
assoc callto
```

callto=URL:Callto Protocol

```
ftype "Callto Protocol"
```

callto="C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" "/callto:"%l""

You can define custom protocols via assoc/ftype while using command line (and of course programmatically). Just remember not to overwrite existing protocols.

You can also use this to define actions for file extensions like `exe` or `txt`.